# Eclipse mars hangs on "preparing launch delegates"

Tags: jsp, eclipse-mars

I am using eclipse mars with j`boss 7.1` and `jdk1.7`
When I start my server it shows

> "preparing launch delegates" inprogress.

Server not changing from starting to started.

Answer (score 1):

you are most probably running the project in debug mode.Try taking F8 to make debug progress further.